# Complex custom control and properties visibility

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls

I'm developing a custom WPF control ("multi selector"). I give my users `ItemsSource` property for binding purposes, but internally I'm using ItemWrappers collection like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TFSControls.MultiSelectorControl.MultiSelectorControl">
    <ItemsControl Name="ItemsPresenter" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemWrappers}">
        ...
    </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

The problem is that in order for this binding to work ItemWrappers property has to be public.
I would be happy with internal, because the control sits in its own assembly.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

The only solution that I'm aware of is to subclass ItemsControl in my assembly, but that doesn't seem right - I need no custom behavior, just want this property to be internal/protected.

Comment: What you are trying to say is, you want some collection property to be exposed from your user control as public but NOT `ItemWrappers`. correct?

Comment: I want ItemWrappers to be internal and to be able to bind to it INSIDE my control, where I'm using ItemsControl (as shown above). The other property (ItemsSource) is not important here, it's mentioned just to say that I have other public property for my users to bind to.
Namely the control should be used like this:
`<tfs:MultiSelectorControl  ItemsSource="{Binding AllWorkers}" SelectedItems="{Binding Path=SelectedWorkers,Mode=TwoWay}" />`

Comment: So in that case why cant you declare your `ItemsWrapper` property as private dependency property Key (i.e. a dependency property which is registered as readonly) then?

Comment: Because it doesn't solve the problem completely. Read my comment below Amits answer.

Comment: Then generalize \ abstract it, use `object` type or abstract the class using some custom interface. Interfaces hide the implementation.

Comment: It's WPF control, a concrete type. If it was something else I would have done so.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `ItemWrappers` a readonly dependency property.

Comment: It's a step in the right direction, but ultimately I want the ItemWrapper class to also be internal - no one has to know how things are done inside the control.

Answer (score 0):

Property must be public, but the object itself may not. So as another possible solution you can encapsulate this property in another class, make an instance of that class private inside your control and bind to it.